# English Rules for the card game Belote

Tags: belote

There is a card game I used to play when I was in school in the Middle East--which I understand is based on a French game called Belote.

Does anyone know of an English set of rules for this game?

The game involves 4 players in two teams, only uses the 7's and up of each suit (A,K,Q,J,10,9,8,7).

Each turn starts with a bidding process for the top card; it's either chosen to be the trump suite or not.

Scoring is different for the trump suit as is, the rank of the cards, (trump: J,9,A,10,K,Q,8,7) vs (non-trump: A,10,K,Q,J,9,8,7).

Each round consists of a player playing one card into the pile, the team with the highest value card wins that round.

There are also sets of cards like three/four/five in a row or 4 of a kind that are worth bonus points.

I'm looking for a concise set of rules in English for this game, preferably the Arabic variant, if not the French original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like I misspelt the name of the game. It's actually Belut or Belote

I've found a set of rules here:

http://www.pagat.com/jass/belote.html

The only difference in rules to what I'm used to that I can see from a glance is that 4 Aces is worth 400 points.

Comment: I usually resort to pagat, as they have an almost comprehensive number of card game rule descriptions.

Answer (score 5):

You can find here : http://en.beloteenligne.com/ some additionnal information.

The Belote rules seems so easy, but there were so much [strategy](http://www.beloteenligne.com/strategies) going on. In France, they prefer a lot Belote to Poker. 
This game is known because in every family (and at school) they play belote on Sunday after the meal.